# Find folders that contain a file (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, find, directory

I have a question regarding some VBA coding. I have an Excel spreadsheet with rows that each contain an identification number (e.g. ABC0123456ABC). I also have a folder with subfolders that have a name similar to the identification number from the Excel file. However, some of these subfolders contain more files (all pdfs). I would like to know which folders contain files (and which do not).

Thus, I would like to search all folders that contain files with the names that are taken from the excel file.

How would I best do this?

Comment: You could use the  FileSystemObject . A google search might throw up examples

Comment: Welcome to SO. *How would I best do this?* You could code some loops to check folders and subfolders and find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I'm relatively new to VBA so where would I start? I found some code on Google that comes close to my solution but I can't seem to make it suit my dataset and folders

Comment: @jtsbattle So for each identification number in your Excel file, you want to find all subfolders (in a particular folder) which contain the identification number in their name -- and then for each of these found subfolders (which do contain the identification number in their name), you want to do what? Check if each subfolder contains PDF files? Check if each subfolder contains any files?

Comment: @chillin I have a list of ID numbers in an Excel file and I have a directory containing a lot of folders that have the same numbers as the ID numbers in the Excel file. So for every ID number in the Excel file, there is a folder available as well. However, some of these folders have files and some are empty. For each ID number in Excel, I would like to know which folders are empty (and thus also which are not). I hope this clarifies it!

Comment: And ideally, the results could be saved in an .txt. file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could modify this to your needs;

If i have a spreadsheet like this (data in range B1:B3);

[image]

where each row represents a sub-folder and you want to know if you have a file in each of these sub-folders

Then you can use this code.  It will write whether there is a file which contains the same name as shown in column B to column C.

```
 Public Sub FindFiles()

Dim myParentFolderLoc As String
Dim curValue As String

Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRange As Range
Dim outputRange As Range

    ' Change these to your range/Folder Location;
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("B1:B3")
    Set outputRange = Sheet1.Range("B1:C3") ' note the inclusion of the column to which i am writing
    myParentFolderLoc = "C:\Example Folder\"

    ' Loop through your excel cells
    For Each myCell In myRange.Cells

        If isFileInFolder(myParentFolderLoc, myCell.Value) Then
            myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Files Exists"
        Else
            myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No Files Exists"
        End If

    Next myCell

    ' Export to Txt
    ExportRangeToTxt outputRange

End Sub


' Loop through the folder and see if a file contains the string
Private Function isFileInFolder(folderLocation As String, folderName As String) As Boolean

   Dim i As Integer
   i = 0
   file = Dir(folderLocation & folderName & "\")

   While (file <> "")
     i = i + 1
     file = Dir
  Wend

    If i > 0 Then
        isFileInFolder = True
    Else
        isFileInFolder = False
    End If


End Function


Private Sub ExportRangeToTxt(myRange As Range)

Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\output.txt"
Set rng = myRange

Open myFile For Output As #1

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
        cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

        If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
            Write #1, cellValue
        Else
            Write #1, cellValue,
        End If
  Next j
Next i

Close #1

MsgBox "Text Export Complete - Check the file at: " & myFile

End Sub
```

This will export a file to the default file path of the application - the message box will tell you where this is.

Remember to update the ranges as shown for the example to include all your sub-folders. I could do this automatically but i dont want to make any assumptions having not seen your data.

Comment: Thanks! However, the files inside the folders do not have the same name as the folder. Thus: I have a list of values in Excel with identification numbers (e.g. ABCDE1234) and I have a list folders that are named the same. However, some of these folders contain files and some don't. I only need to known which folders contain files or which are empty

Comment: Ideally, the results could be saved in a .txt file

Comment: so what is in your excel sheet is a folder - and you need to know what folders have files in them? and they are all subfolders underneath a parent folder?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need!

Comment: go on then.. its friday I will add the .txt thing.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: quick question: does this code also search subfolders? I have a new dataset now which goes one level higher.