# Check directories for file containing cell data then add text to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

In my head this sounded quite simple, but I am quickly discovering I have more questions on how to proceed than I initially thought. Such as, how do I loop it through several directories? How do I get it to not include LogNumber "1" in LogNumber "1001"? etc

I will try to keep it simple and I can change cell and folders etc later.

Let's say, I have a sheet with the table as such in columns A and B, with the headers on row 1;

| Log Number | Document Tracker |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | NBI |
| 101001 | Authorized |
| 2001 | NBI |
| 202001 | Authorized |
| 2003 | Awaiting Check |
| 3004 | Rejected |

I have files in several folders, in this case, to reflect the table.

"1001 Supplier A.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Files\NBI"

"101001 Supplier A.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Files\Authorized"

"2001 Supplier B.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Files\NBI"

"202001 Supplier C.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Files\Authorized"

"2003 Supplier B.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Files\Awaiting Check"

"3004 Supplier F.pdf" is in folder "C:\Documents\Processed\Rejected"

I would like the vba script to search through the folder locations above for a file containing a matching Log Number. Then, if such a file exists, it will put into Document Tracker column some relevant text, not necessarily the folder name. So if its in folder "NBI" it says "NBI" in the relevant cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is "1001 Supplier A.pdf" a generic name? I mean, should it **start with so named Long Number(LN)**, or this LN must only be part of it? Then, will LN be followed by the string " Supplier"?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239732/4717755) should provide some help to get started.

Comment: @FaneDuru yes the files start with LN, and it is then followed by Supplier, and then another number not relevant to this topic.

Comment: I adapted my answer to treat the situation as described in the above comment. It should work for all of them...

Comment: @PeterT thanks for the link I will look into it, it definitely seems related to what I've asked, and I have seen some other related ones such as..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443778/find-folders-that-contain-a-file-vba

Which also seemed quite close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that the file name **starts with the Long Number followed by " Suppl"**, please try the next code. It will return all the files confirmed path by adding "OK" in `arrFin`. The content of `arrFin` is dropped in C:C column, but it can be dropped anywhere it's necessary:

```
Sub MatchFileExistence()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long
 Const comPath As String = "C:\Documents\Files\"
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column A:A
 
 arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the existence confirmation
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Dir(comPath & arr(i, 2) & "\" & arr(i, 1) & " Supp*.pdf") <> "" Then
        arrFin(i, 1) = "OK" 'use here what confirmation string you need...
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the processed array result:
 sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version. It will check all Long numbers from A:A column in all folders from the `arrFolders` array and returns the subfolder where the file has been found. If found it in many places, it will return the locations separated by "|":

```
Sub MatchFileExistence()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, El, arrFolders, i As Long
 Const comPath As String = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\Folders\"  '"C:\Documents\Files\"
 arrFolders = Split("NBI,Authorized,Awaiting Check,Rejected", ",") 'place subfolders in a list
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column A:A
  'in case of placing the necessary folders in column B:B, please uncomment the next line
 'arrFolders = sh.Range("B2", sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value2

 arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the existence confirmation
 
 For Each El In arrFolders
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
           If Dir(comPath & El & "\" & arr(i, 1) & " *.pdf") <> "" Then
               If arrFin(i, 1) = "" Then
                    arrFin(i, 1) = El
                Else
                    arrFin(i, 1) = arrFin(i, 1) & "|" & El
                End If
           End If
        Next i
 Next El
 'drop the processed array result:
 sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

It will drop the processing result in the same C:C column, starting from the second row.

If you intend to place the folders in a range (on a column, let us say B:B), please uncomment the line `'arrFolders = sh.Range("B2", sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value2`... If not B:B, update the code to match the really used column.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version. It will firstly return an array of occurrences for the root folder and all its subfolders, then the array will be evaluated to extract the file folder:

```
Sub MatchFileExistenceX()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, arrFiles, El, arrFld
 Const comPath As String = "C:\Documents\Files\"
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column A:A
 
 arr = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR).Value2
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the array to keep the existence confirmation
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
   If Not IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then
     arrFiles = getAllFls(comPath, arr(i, 1) & " *.pdf")
     If UBound(arrFiles) > -1 Then
        For Each El In arrFiles
             arrFld = Split(El, "\")
             If arrFin(i, 1) = "" Then
                    arrFin(i, 1) = arrFld(UBound(arrFld) - 1)
             Else
                    arrFin(i, 1) = arrFin(i, 1) & "|" & arrFld(UBound(arrFld) - 1)
             End If
        Next El
     End If
   End if
 Next i
 'drop the processed array result:
 sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub

Private Function getAllFls(strFold As String, Optional strExt As String = "*.*") As Variant
    getAllFls = filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c dir """ & strFold & strExt & """ /b/s").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), "\")
End Function
```

Please, use as `comPath` the root folder containing all the others as subfolders...

Now I will leave my office. If something not clear, please ask for clarifications, but I will answer when I will be at home.

Comment: Hi Fane, this works quite well actually, thank you for this. There is some relevant feedback and you did already touch on it a bit, but I will expand here.

Firstly, I noticed that it can only search 1 folder though, the folder provided in comPath. But it needs to check several locations for the file.

Secondly, as touched on before, if there is a "1" and a "101", both will get trigged by "1". This might not be too much of an issue as I believe the files are handled relatively quickly, and are quite large numbers already so it is rare this will happen. As an example of how the files

Comment: labelled, it will be like this;

"2000182 Google 2918.pdf"
"2000183 Apple 3896.pdf"
"2000184 Currys 1239.pdf"

The second number is irrelevant to this task. The supplier name IS in the spreadsheet is required, in a separate column. 

Thirdly, a most important task required of the script is that it doesn't simply say "OK" but instead inserts text into the cell related to WHICH folder it found the file in. If it found it in folder "NBI" it should say "NBI" if it found it in folder "Tony" it needs to say "Awaiting authorization"

I hope this makes sense? and I appreciate the help so far

Comment: @InvkrMainr I am afraid, it does not make more sense... You said "yes the files start with LN, and it is then followed by Supplier", but I can see, now name files as "2000182 Google ...", "2000184 Currys ...", which does not respect the patter consistency. Then, what "Document Tracker" should be? The folder where the file has been found? I understood that it makes part of the path where to search for... So, if I would say that you want searching **all Long Numbers**, **followed by a space** in **some folders**, will it be a correct understanding? If so, where from to be taken the folders list?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Supplier" as in a variable. I was just using "Supplier" as I did not want to provide specific names. 

"Document Tracker" will be text, related to what folder the file was found in. For example, if it found the file in "NBI" the cell should say "NBI", if found in "Tony" it should say "Awaiting authorization" if found in "Rejected" it should say "Rejected". I can sort this bit out if there is a framework for me to add to.

Your understand seems to be correct, I can put folder list in the spreadsheet itself if that is easier. Just point it to a column/range and I can amend.

Comment: @InvkrMainr Is understanding that all folders root is the one I used as constant, would be a correct one? Then, I cannot understand why  **if found in "Tony" it should say "Awaiting authorization"** and not "Tony", according to the rule you set before...

Comment: I haven't tested your update yet, but to answer your question, because there will be many folders such as "Tony", "James", "Cheryl" that should be reflected as "Awaiting Authroization". It is not the end of the world if it doesn't say that, but that is the intention

Comment: @InvkrMainr It is not a matter of being end of the world. But in order to design a solution, the logic part of the code must be perfectly defined. If you settle which such folder names should return such a string, I can adapt the code to do it. But you did not confirm that all folders **are subfolders of the same main folder**, the one used as a constant in my code(s). If you are not cristal clear from this point of view, I only design codes based on my suppositions, which can solve the issue only by chance...

Comment: Sorry Fane, I had no chance yesterday to reply or test the script. But I do now.

I did not answer the original question as I figured I could make it work without answering it. It does somewhat work by inputting within arrFolders = Split ("Authorized\HR,Rejected,Authorized\Tony", ",").

They can all be traced back to an original folder, yes. Which I can input in comPath, and then branch from there.

The code you have written has worked fantastically, I am trying to add to it by changing  the folder named cells to something different but failing sadly.

Comment: I wanted to use a For Loop, with If Else If statements for each folder, but doing some would put Excel out of memory as it will have to do 20000+ cells in real usage sadly.

Comment: @InvkrMainr I firstly feel the need to say that I cannot get you... Secondly, I would like to appreciate that focusing on clarifying my questions will be more productive. I have în mind some other possibilities. For instance, I can supply a piece of code able to search in all subfolders up to the last level, but only **if you are able to supply the root folder**. Without dealing with checking in each folder. What about answering the above bolded question: **are all folders to be returned subfolders of the same main folder**? Expressed in a different way but with the same meaning.

Comment: @InvkrMainr Please, test the updated answer and send some feedback.

Comment: In this specific case the nearest root folder is merely the "M:\" drive. It then goes in two different directions. With folders in different locations. Personally, your second edited answer, was the best for this use case, as I can simply add or remove directories at will within the arrFolders split variable.

No, all folders are not subfolders of the same main folder. Some of them are 4/5 subfolders deep in a different direction to the rest. 

Sadly I cannot test the second function as it is blocked on the domain, presumably because it opens cmd.

Comment: Ideally, I just need the function to search within the provided array folders.

Comment: Why don't you use "M:\"? Iam driving now...

Comment: I can use M:\, it is no problem to me, I just am testing the script on a local C:\ location rather than the live production drive. I know enough of vba to detect and change variables to an extent so I knew I could correct.

Comment: I still cannot get you... the code does not change anything! It only read! It cannot harm anything...

Comment: Sorry I did not reply, I got covid at the time and have been very unwell and resting. It was more so not wanting to give folder names to a public forum as the names contain personal and business information, that was all.

Comment: @InvkrMainr I hope you are well now. Is that true? Then, I only wanted to make you testing the code in the real environment, **to see if your user permissions allow using of the function I posted**. Of course, you could change 4-5 cells with the real names, without nobody here knowing it... :)

Comment: I am well now, thank you!
I have just tried it in the real environment and it seems to work well (the 2nd one in your op). The only problem I am having, is that column A where it gets the numbers from, is full of VLOOKUPS to get the number. which is not a problem, except a lot of them are for future numbers, so are just "N/A". Would it be possible to get a workaround that it ignores N/A VLOOKUPS? If it helps, as soon as it hits an N/A it can stop looking.

Comment: @InvkrMainr OK, I will adapt the code. Adapted. `If Not IsError(arr(i, 1)) Then` should do what you need, even not tested. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: @InvkrMainr Should I understand that it did not work as you need. Some feedback will be welcomed... Besides all that, I will also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we vote if up and most important, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...